# NextJS server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building an app using NextJS and its server side rendering feature.

If I understood it correctly, to take advantage of it all we need to do is exporting an async function called `getServerSideProps` in the component we want to server side render.

Curious thing is I noticed my components were being server side rendered even without exporting `getServerSideProps` function.

Is there any other thing (other than getServerSideProps) that can cause a component to be server side rendered?

Thanks in advance

Additional information:

the directories are like this:

- root

  - src

    - components

      - layout

        - Header.tsx
        - Sidebar.tsx
      - viewport

        - ViewportContext.tsx
    - pages

      - users

        - Index.tsx
      - ...

Also, this `ViewportContext.tsx` relies in the window variable to determine if the client is mobile or desktop.

NextJs version is 13.0.5

Right now, for every request the `console.log()`s I placed in the components are displayed in the terminal, meaning that there is some server render (I guess) running.

Comment: What version of nextjs do you use ?

Comment: NextJs version is 13.0.5

Answer (score 0):

In NextJS as you can see here, the default behaviour is Static Generation : https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-without-data

In version 13 : https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/static-and-dynamic-rendering

Answer (score 0):

NextJS will always render on the server (and hydrate again on the client). However, without dynamic data from `getServerSideProps` it can already be rendered during the build and then cached. With `getServerSideProps` the page will be rendered anew with the up-to-date data for every request by a user. In this case the page will be rendered in a Serverless function.

Comment: It makes sense. I think using the new `app` directory will lead to this behavior. I'm still using the previous `src/pages` though (I'll add some additional information in the question about it)